# Symfony 3: How to redirect from within InteractiveLoginEvent listener

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

In Symfony 3.4.0, from an event listener that listens to the `InteractiveLoginEvent` I would like to redirect to another route, so I would like to respond a redirect.

But the `InteractiveLoginEvent` object has no "setResponse" method. So which is the preferred way to use the `InteractiveLoginEvent` to modify the response so that a redirect is sent to the user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To perform a redirect after successful login, you can add a custom success handler, that should implement the [AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface](http://api.symfony.com/3.4/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface.html).

AuthenticationSuccessHandler.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Handler;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;

class AuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface
{
    private $router;

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('homepage'));
    }
}
```

services.yml

```
   services:
       AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Handler:
           arguments: ['@router']
```

security.yml

```
security:
    # ...
    firewalls:
          form_login:
              # ...
              use_referer: false
              success_handler: AppBundle\Security\Authentication\Handler\AuthenticationSuccessHandler
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to also call the "normal" success handler from within this customized one, or do I always have to do all the handling manually in here once I defined my own handler? Because I just need the custom redirect on some conditions, otherwise the "normal" handling (redirect to target URL saved in session) is just fine.

Comment: I also posted this as a new question as the answer may maybe not short:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47650672/symfony-3-call-default-success-handler-from-within-custom-success-handler)

Comment: The best way is to extend the DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler and override the onAuthenticationSuccess method. And use parent:: onAuthenticationSuccess in case of default behaviour needed.

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked in the comment, instead of just implementing the entire interface yourself, you can extend the default success handler, override the success method, do what you want with it, and then call the parent method to allow symfony to do its normal thing

Click below for a full example of how to override the handler
https://www.codereviewvideos.com/course/symfony-3-for-beginners/video/bonus-how-to-show-a-flash-message-on-successful-login-or-failed-login-attempt